# C# - Wait for process to exit and close 'ShowDialog()'

Tags: c#, modal-dialog, task

Being new to .net, i am not able to get how to close the show dialog modal window once its open. As i have learnt we cannot close that automatically until explicitly its to be called. Here is my code:

```
//process - notepad.exe 
Process p = Process.Start(process); 
frm_Save fsave = new frm_Save(); 

Using (p)
{ 
    do
    { 
        if(!p.HasExited)    
        {
            p.Refresh();
            fsave.ShowDialog(); // it just stuck here and doesn't go to next line
        }
    } 
    while(!p.WaitForExit(1000)); 
}

//frm_Save.cs 
public frm_Save() 
{ 
    InitializeComponent(); 
}

private void frm_Save_Load(...,....)
{ 
    // 
}

private void frm_Save_Shown(...,...) 
{ 
    Sleep(100); 
    Forms.Application.DoEvents();
    Close(); 
}
```

Comment: please format your code, its unreadable

Comment: yup i just submitted an edit for that...

Comment: Sorry for the indentation, as I am posting from mobile app

Comment: Is there a reason why you're using `ShowDialog` and not `Show`?

Comment: John, Show doesn't show the dialog on foreground at all and it hangs and opens up multiple windows until the process is exited. And i want to block user for further actions, hence modal.

Comment: Could you explain what you aim with `WaitForExit`? What do you want to achieve? Because it is in conflict with the purpose of `ShowDialog`. When `ShowDialog` is called, the code following it is not executed until after the dialog box is closed.

Comment: Yes the process here is not notepad but a console app trying to do some video editing and while its still processing I am showing a message and gif icon stating that video is saving and blocking user for not performing any other tasks.

Comment: There is an exited event

Comment: @highlander141 so this is not the way to achieve this. You have to use background thread for computing and the main Thread for the UI. Try to use `BackgroundWorker`: https://learn.microsoft.com/de-de/dotnet/api/system.componentmodel.backgroundworker?view=netframework-4.7.2

Comment: You should set the DialogResult of the frm_save. I think that now your frm_save doesn't 'return' anything that's why it's stuck, e.g: if you are saving something with a button click than you can set the DialogResult property of that form in the click even, DialogResult = DialogResult.OK(or any other).

Comment: @CodePope, so the process will run in Backgroundworker class and once it returns, what is the next step, some pseudo code would really help here.

Answer (score 1):

This approach may work for you, note the use of TopMost.

```
using System.Runtime.InteropServices; 

private static readonly IntPtr HWND_TOPMOST = new IntPtr(-1);
private const UInt32 SWP_NOSIZE = 0x0001;
private const UInt32 SWP_NOMOVE = 0x0002;
private const UInt32 TOPMOST_FLAGS = SWP_NOMOVE | SWP_NOSIZE;   

[DllImport("user32.dll")] 
[return: MarshalAs(UnmanagedType.Bool)]
public static extern bool SetWindowPos(IntPtr hWnd, IntPtr hWndInsertAfter, 
  int X, int Y, int cx, int cy, uint uFlags);
```

....

```
frm_Save fsave = new frm_Save(); 
fsave.Show();

SetWindowPos(frm_Save.Handle, HWND_TOPMOST, 0, 0, 0, 0, TOPMOST_FLAGS);

Process p = Process.Start(process); 

using (p)
{
    while (!p.WaitForExit(1000))
    {
        fsave.Refresh();
    }
}
fsave.Close();
```

Comment: Thanks, but still the Form executes in background and cannot be seen on top of main application

Comment: Try moving the Process.Start after the form has shown. I have edited the code to show this.

Comment: No still not, its in the background of application. And i think show is what I need and not showdialog. Any other way to show the dialog on top of main ui?

Comment: I have edited with a new way to try. The 'using' should go up the top of your class file with the other 'using'. The other code can go in your class declaration. Note the line 'SetWindowPos(frm_Save.Handle, HWND_TOPMOST, 0, 0, 0, 0, TOPMOST_FLAGS);'

Answer (score 1):

As you have explained, you want to show a dialog with icon that you are saving a video in the background and prevent the user to do something. One regular way to do that is with a `BackgroundWorker` in your Dialog. Here is the code how it would work:

```
public class frm_Save : Form
{
    public FrmProgress(List<TransferOptions> transferOptions)
    {
        InitializeComponent();
        BackgroundWorker BgrdWorker = new System.ComponentModel.BackgroundWorker();
        this.BgrdWorker.DoWork += new System.ComponentModel.DoWorkEventHandler(this.BgrdWorker_DoWork);
        this.BgrdWorker.RunWorkerCompleted += new System.ComponentModel.RunWorkerCompletedEventHandler(this.BgrdWorker_RunWorkerCompleted);
    }

    private void FrmProgress_Load(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        // Show image and message...
    }

    private void BgrdWorker_DoWork(object sender, DoWorkEventArgs e)
    {
        // Call your video Process start Function
        // after that
        var stopWatch = new StopWatch();
        stopWatch.Start()
        while (true)
        {
            if (stopWatch.ElapsedMilliseconds >1000 || videoProcessHasReturnedSuccessfully)
            {
                break
            }
        }
    }

    private void BgrdWorker_RunWorkerCompleted(object sender, RunWorkerCompletedEventArgs e)
    {
        // inform the user the video processing is finished
        this.Close();
    }
}
```

Then in the main form of your console app when you want to start the whole process, you call:

```
frm_Save fsave = new frm_Save(); 
fsave.ShowDialog()
```

Tip: You can also use `BgrdWorker.ProgressChanged` to show the progress of background task to the user by communicating between the background task and the UI if necessary, but you have not requested that in your question.

Comment: Great! But the problem here is the video processing helper utility is a 64bit application and this process is being called in 32bit application. So as you said i cannot do the video processing task in _DoWork and rather have to wait till the process is completed with a exit code 0.

Comment: Why don't you wait in `BgrdWorker_DoWork` until the process is completed with an exit code 0? Run the process and wait until you get exit code 0. Then exit the `BgrdWorker_DoWork` event. The only general problem is calling a 64bit app from 32 bit, but this another problem and not related to the question mentioned in this thread. But if you have solved the problem calling a 64bit app from 32 bit and getting return value from 64bit after finishing, then just do it in the `BgrdWorker_DoWork` event

Comment: Yes its working. I have only two doubts- 1. As we are using Backgroundworker class, DoEvents() is not required, am I right? 2. In the waitforexit method, if the video processing takes a lot if time and couldn't return with in 1000ms, shall I give waitforexit(0), in this case? Please clarify.

Comment: 1. I don't know why exactly you are using `DoEvent`, but for Backgroundworker you don't need to call it generally. The `RunWorkerCompleted` event is called automatically after the `DoWork` event is executed.
2. In my sample code I don't use the `WaitForExit1` method. I have update the `BgrdWorker_DoWork` function to show you how you would check if there is a return value and exit the thread and close the `frm_Save` if it does not return until 1000ms.